# How to forward success and fail callbacks of jQuery functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, wrapper

I would like to wrap some jQuery functions (namely ajax) for several reasons, such as global configuration of parameters and, more importantly, being able to exchange it easily.

My question is, how can I "forward" the `.done()` and `.fail()` callbacks? (Which design-pattern is responsible for this behavior of jQuery?)

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://url.com",
})
  .done(function( data ) {
    // do something
  })
.fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  });
```

For clarification, what I would like to be able to do is writing a function which wraps the above function and behaves like this:

```
myWrapper({config: "abc"}).done(function( data ) {
    // do something
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$.ajax` function does return a [promise object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) which offers these methods (`done`, `fail`, `always`, most important `then`). Just return that object from your `myWrapper` function.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that these methods return the same promise object again? So if I specify a `.fail` method in my wrapper I can use it as default behavior and return the promise object?

Comment: Check their docs. `done` and `fail` do, `then` doesn't for example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the `ajax` call if you want to do that...

```
function myWrapper(config) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: "http://url.com",
        data: config
    });
}
```

and then call like you suggested...

```
myWrapper({ config: "abc" }).done(function(data) {
    // call is done
});
```

I've obviously made assumptions in the above code, but it should get the point across clearly enough.  If not, just ask :)